# How to extract the values from a string from slack ruby bot

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, bots, slack

I am trying to create a slackbot which can save incoming data to a database.

I have used the gem `slack-ruby-bot` and I'm able to receive my text, but I want to extract specific parts of the text, to save in a database.

#### Given the following received text:

- I worked on 'stackoverflow' for 10 hours.

I must be able to extract the project name, **stackoverflow**, and the hour, which is **10**. Is there someway to do it?

```
  command 'activity', '/^Activity/' do |client, data, match|
    client.say(text: "#{data.text}", channel: data.channel)
  end
```

This is just a sample code which gets the command activity.

Comment: Text has been updated for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wherever you receive the string, you might use the regular expression and `String#scan` to get the data.

```
"I worked on 'stackoverflow' for 10 hours.".scan /'[^']+'|\d+/
#⇒ ["'stackoverflow'", "10"]
```